# Static library segfaults when calling another static library

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

I have created a static library, A, from one of my C++ projects which I can use in another project, X.

However, some functions from my static library, A, call other functions in static library B (the DevIL image loading library). Hence, to compile my project X, I have included both A and B in the linker and it compiles fine.

The problem is my program has a segmentation fault only when I call functions from library A which in turn call Library B.

Are there any ways to get around this? Should I combine libraries A and B into one library (there are no licensing issues affecting this)? I am using Visual Studio 2013 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Build both the application and the libraries with debug-info, then run in a debugger to catch the crash.

Comment: I have stepped through the debugger. I don't have the source for the dependent library, B, but the error occurs in a function where B allocates memory.

Comment: And how are you calling that function? Are you sure the problem is not in your code (in how you call the function, the arguments you pass, etc)?

Comment: No, because if I compile A as an executable instead of a library, and A calls the same function in B, it works fine.

Comment: There are several possible pb: is this related to callback functions ? Does it happen when one lib manages memory allocated by the other ? You must provide much more infos for us to be able to help...

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems linking libraries in the right order. Check that.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: The order in which you link the .a files in CMake matters.

Comment: But op uses msvc and there it sould'nt matter: if there would be conflicts btw symbols the linker would complain

Comment: I don't have experience with MSVC. I did see something like this happen in *nix OSs.